# trying to connect to google meet conversation using selenium running on kubernetes running on AWS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots, google-meet

i have a bot that you can invite to a google meet conversation by sending an email.
the code for connecting to the conversation is:

```
       url = f"https://meet.google.com/{self.meeting_link}"
        log.info("Connecting to url: " + url)

        try:
            
            browser.get(url)
            browser.save_screenshot("test.png")
            # element = WebDriverWait(browser, MAX_RETRIES).until(
            #     EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']"))
            # )
            # log.info("Found element")

            # Fill the name
            # element[0].send_keys(self._bot_name)
            browser.save_screenshot("test2.png")
            # Now ask to join
            try:
                atj_element = WebDriverWait(browser, MAX_RETRIES).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                        (By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Ask to join')]")
                    )
                )
            except Exception as e:
                log.exception(e)
                log.info("Could not find ask to join button, trying join now")
                atj_element = None
            if atj_element is None:
                try:
                    atj_element = WebDriverWait(browser, MAX_RETRIES).until(
                        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                            (By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Join now')]")
                        )
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    log.exception(e)
                    log.info("Could not find join now button")
                    atj_element = None

            browser.save_screenshot("test3.png")
            atj_element[0].click()

            # log.debug(browser.page_source)

            browser.save_screenshot("screenshot_in_waiting_room.png")
            log.info("Requested to join meeting, waiting to join")

            md_element = WebDriverWait(browser, MAX_RETRIES).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(
                    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[aria-label='Leave call']")
                )
            )

            browser.save_screenshot("screenshot_after_joining_audio.png")
            log.info("Joined meeting")

            browser.save_screenshot("screenshot_after_joining_video.png")
            if should_init:
                log.info("Moving microphone to a different sink")
                log.info(run([MOVE_SINK_COMMAND]))

        except Exception as e:
            log.exception(e)
            browser.quit()
            return False
```

the web driver settings:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    def _init_selenium_chrome_undetected(self):
        opt = uc.ChromeOptions()
        opt.add_argument("--headless")
        opt.add_argument("--enable-logging")
        opt.add_argument("--v=1")
        opt.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        opt.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
        opt.add_argument("--incognito")
        opt.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
        opt.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        opt.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
        opt.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        opt.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        opt.add_experimental_option(
            "prefs",
            {
                "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
                "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
                "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 0,
                "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1,
            },
        )
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=opt)
        driver.set_window_size(1280, 720)
        self._browser = driver
        return driver
```

when i run the code on my computer every thin work as aspected and the bot connect to the invited meet conversation.
but when i deploy it to AWS it failed, because google block it and i'm getting a page with msg You can't join this video call. your meeting is safe...

i tried adding login to a google account before, but google also block it with a verify page.
and tried to use firefox as well with no success